# lyx 3 column document

Tags: lyx, columns

I am using LyX and would like to create a document with 3 vertical columns. I noticed there was a built-in option for 2 columns, i.e. Document->Settings->Text Layout->Two-column document. Is there an option for 3 columns? If not, is it possible to create it with a LaTeX preamble? (at the beginning of the LyX document)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package. You need to add

```
\usepackage{multicol}
```

to the LaTeX preamble (Document -> Settings -> LaTeX preamble).

[image]

You also need to insert two lines of ERT

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
```

and

```
\end{multicols}
```

Everything between these two is now in a three-column layout.

[image]

Comment: Great answer, still relevant today!